# Themes and editing pages in Sitefinity 4.4

Tags: themes, sitefinity

When I edit content in the backend I would like to be able to see the page as like it is in sitefinity 3.7. Right now all I'm seeing are the contentplaceholders, I don't think this is will work for inexperienced users. Is this this possible to achieve? I've tried adding themes="theme" to the  tag in the web config, but this applies it to the CMS elements as well.

Sitefinity version: 4.4

Thanks for your time!

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply styles for particular elements only for the page editor (placeholders, widget headers etc.), put `.sfPageContainer` before every element. For example, if you want to change the color of the links in the page editor write `.sfPageContainer a{color:blue}` and this will apply only in the page editor, not in the whole system.